# Is to possible to load the selective data from file to ADW through Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I wanted to know whether we will be able to load the selective data from file to ADW through Azure pipeline.

I will be getting full file daily and I have to load the data into ADW. But I just have to load only the last 2 days data from the file. The file will have the date to represent the data.

I have gone through pipeline documentation and couldn't find any way to filter out the data directly from file.

Could anyone please suggest whether it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the data file is a csv file or similar in blob storage or data lake store, you can create an external table in ADW which maps the data file. Then you can use a select query to retrieve data for the last 2 days when loading data from the external table.

/Magnus